# Google Sheets formula for weekly column totals

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm a bit of a newbie to Google Sheets formulas and such.

I have a set of data entered daily with the dates converted by WEEKNUM() to display and allow me to filter by week no. I want to add the values for a number of entries by the resultant week no. to obtain a weekly total for different columns.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If column B has week number and columns E,F,G,H,I,J have quantities for which you need weekly totals, then [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) returns the relevant totals:

```
=query(B:J, "select B, sum(E), sum(F), sum(G), sum(H), sum(I), sum(J) group by B")
```

Alternatively, you can create a [pivot table report](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, that has been a great help. I greatly appreciate the help.